# How to solve "cannot find symbol" error, generated by method Timeout.seconds() from "org. junit.rules.Timeout" package?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, compiler-errors

Have patience, I'm learning.
I am doing java homeworks where I have to implement methods and test them.
I state that I imported the packages and created the necessary interface and class.
In this case I have to test the "add" method, but during compilation, I get this error.what does it mean? How I can solve it ?

`Error:(15, 47) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method seconds(int)
  location: class org.junit.rules.Timeout`

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.*;


public class StringCalculatorTest {

    @Rule
    public Timeout globalTimeout = Timeout.seconds(2);

    Calculator calculator = null;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        calculator = new StringCalculator();
    }

    @Test
    public void calculatorTest() {
        assertThat(calculator.add("")).isEqualTo(0);
        assertThat(calculator.add("1,3")).isEqualTo(4);
    }
```

This is StringCalculator class.

```
public class StringCalculator implements Calculator {
    public int add(String expression){
        return 0;
    }

}
```

And this is calculator interface.

```
public interface Calculator{
    int add(String expression);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the role of the timeout in your example. Maybe just remove it?

The test itself works nicely for me if I change the assertions slightly:

```
    assertEquals(calculator.add(""), 0);
    assertEquals(calculator.add("1,3"), 4);
```

The second one fails as expected, since the implementation of the calculator is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look something like this:

Timeout timeout = new Timeout(int milisecunds);